# how to update default profile pic localhost php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update the default profile picture 
 MY form is

```
    <div class="profile-photo-container">
    <img src="images/profile-photo.jpg" alt="Profile Photo" class="img-responsive" />
</div>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method=post enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input type=hidden name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000" />
    <input type=submit value=submit />
</form>
```

And display code is

upload code is from this [link](https://forgetcode.com/PHP/539-Photo-Upload-and-Retrive-with-MySql-using-BLOB)

Comment: Whats use of Mysql ?

Comment: Where is your PHP-code?

Comment: Add your code tried so far

Comment: I provide in the link

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any php code but here is a code I use: please pay attention this is very basic, check security, etc.
Create a form:

```
<form action="handler.php" method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
Profile Description : <input type="text" name="description"/>
<input type="file" name="profile" value="profile" accept="image/png"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

handler.php

```
$name= $_FILES['profile']['name'];
$tmp_name= $_FILES['profile']['tmp_name'];
$submitbutton= $_POST['submit'];
$position= strpos($profile, "."); 
$fileextension= substr($name, $position + 1);
$fileextension= strtolower($fileextension);
$description=$_POST['description'];

if (isset($name)) {

$path= 'path/to-your-upload/folder/';
if (!empty($name)){
if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $path.$name)) {
echo 'Uploaded to Server !';

//connection to database
$conn= mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password);
if (!$conn)
{
die ('Could not connect:' . mysqli_error($conn));
}
mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbase);

if(!empty($description)){
mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE $table SET description= '".$description."',  profile_pic='".$name."' WHERE user_id='".$_SESSION['user_id']."' AND user_email='".$_SESSION['user_email']."'   ");
}
mysqli_close($conn);
```